# Dynamically change labels depending on zoom in ApexChart

Tags: javascript, zooming, apexcharts

I am currently using ApexChart to create a Graph where I would like to display the time that a user has been connected to a service (Y axis) depending on the dates of connection (X axis).

However, since a user can log in multiple times in the same day to use the service for different amount of times, and he also may not wish to use the service for multiple month at a time, I am having troubles to find a correct way to handle the X Axis labels: if I show only the date, it is difficult to differentiate the multiple connections made in a single day. On the other hand, if I put the date and the time of each connection, there is too much information on screen when we want to display connections made in a single day.

I would therefore like to change the format of my X-axis labels depending on the zoom: if the data displayed to the user is the data corresponding to the connections made in a single day, then I would like to display the time, and else I would like to only display the time.

I have checked Apex Chart API but I do not see anything on how to get back the visible data, or on how to get back zoom information.

[Graph of the duration of connection by day of connection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rVkOd.png)

Thanks in advance for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

The prédéfinie "datetime" type do the job for you as your xaxis categories are dates :

`xaxis:{ type: "datetime", }`
Here is the example with labels changes when ZoomIn/ZoomOut
[example](https://apexcharts.com/javascript-chart-demos/area-charts/spline/) https://apexcharts.com/javascript-chart-demos/area-charts/spline/

Comment: Hello Poly Hamza,
Thanks a lot for your answer ! 
Indeed, I have for now used "category" as the type for xaxis because I would like to see all my nodes evenly spaced out, i.e. with the same space inbetween each of them. If my user has been connected many times on the same day, and then many times two month later, I do not want to see two clusters of points, but rather evenly space out points. Do you know if there is a way to do that and still have the formatting of the text of the datetime type ?